# iOS app will save password but will not autofill

Tags: ios, autofill

I have associated domains set up with my app & api, so apple is asking to save my passwords, but they will not autofill.

Here is my AD:

[image]

Here is XCode where I set the content type:

[image]

[image]

NOTE: The text field input placeholder is "Email", because we use the email as the username.

I even set them programmatically as well. I have tried deleting the app, restarting my phone and deleting the app, deleting the text fields and recreating them, all to no avail.

What is really weird is that autofill for email does not work in my signup form either, but only for that text field. So, I have a first name text field - that will autofill my name, but if i switch that to "Email", then it will autofill email successfully. Then, I copy that text field, move it into position, delete the old one, change one of them back to "first name" and now it doesn't work. This is so weird, it makes 0 sense.

Once I log in, it asks to "Save Password", no matter how many times I log in. It does not ask to "Update Password". When I sign in the second time, I click on "Passwords" and it shows the password I created, attached to my associated domain, under suggested passwords. If I click here, it will load the password. But why is it not autofilling? What am I doing wrong?

I have verified that it autofills in other apps, I just tried w/ CapitalOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the **path** of the associated domain. **This is an apple bug**. For the associated domain, I was using webcredentials:api.companyname.com/v1. The "v1" was the issue. It compiles, runs, and saves the domains with the v1. It appears that about half of the associated domains functionality still works if you include a path, but half doesn't, with no indication of the error. However, when you prepare for submission to the app store by archiving the app, it will fail. When I removed the path, it started to work 100%.